# Get RowCount of SSRS report in code behind

Tags: reporting-services, rowcount

I have a ssrs report. I need the count of rows displayed in code behind. I know CountRows("dataset")  gives no of rows in the report. But is there any way I can get that value in code behind?

Comment: What do you mean by code behind? I guess you need conditionally count some rows, let me know if so,

Comment: I'm launching ssrs report from aspx page. So I need to access the row count in that aspx page.

Comment: server report / local report ?

Comment: Server report. Not local

Comment: there is no way to do row count for server report from code behind. For your expectation, i guess you can copy the same query from SSRS dataset, and paste it to your backend to do COUNT().

Comment: OK thank you. Will try the same.